# Getting prepend_view_path "app/views/ current namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

In my ApplicationController I have this:

```
def prepend_view_paths
      prepend_view_path "app/views/#{request.subdomain}_subdomain" if request.subdomain.present?
    end
```

I want something like this:

```
def prepend_view_paths
      prepend_view_path "app/views/#{current namespace }_namespace" if there is a current namespace
    end
```

Comment: No, I have my controllers split up into three namespaces, and my partials split up into in folders called base in each corresponding view namespace, and I'm trying to figure out how to get a controller that inherits from a gem controller to also know where my partials are stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a better solution to this is simply to make the path to your partials more explicit. So in my example, in my Application layout file I changed the partial path from this:

```
<%= render "menu" %>
```

to this:

```
<%= render "account/base/menu" %>
```

This works because rails looks for the partial in the regular places, but can't find it and throws an error. Specifying exactly where the partial can be found when putting the partial into your HTML solves the problem of Rails or any gems from not knowing where your partials are.